# SwiftPM package discovery tool

Tags: swift

What is a good way to discover available Swift Packages that work with Swift Package Manager and that I can import in my own Swift package?

https://swiftmodules.com/ seems to be down and IBM deprecated Swift Package Catalog (https://developer.ibm.com/swift/2017/12/07/package-catalog-sandbox-deprecation/)

Is there something like https://www.npmjs.com/ for SwiftPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a reply on swift.org forum; sharing it here to spread the knowledge in case others are looking for more info on SwiftPM tools.

The link to the original source:
https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-package-discovery-tool-website/18392

The link to the github project:
https://github.com/Ether-CLI/Ether

Answer (score 0):

There isn't at the moment.. IBM had one up for a while but that died down.. It appears that for now, SPM won't have the same sort of relationship as "NPM" (node package manager) does with modules.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SwiftPM has been registered at https://libraries.io. https://libraries.io/swiftpm